# express session Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, express-session

```
var redis = require('redis');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var client  = redis.createClient();
var session = require('express-session'),
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(session({
    store : new RedisStore({
    host:'localhost',
    port:7351,
    maxAge: 300000,
    client:client,
    ttl:260
   }
 ),
 secret:'dafdsa',
resave:false,
saveUninitialized:true,
}));
```

this is my setting and this is my code

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.body.userid;
  var passwd = req.body.password;
  var sess = req.session;
  var login_chk = pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
      connection.query('SELECT U_passwd FROM Member WHERE U_id = ?',[id],function(err,row,req){
         if(err)console.log(err);
      var sqlpasswd = row[0].U_passwd;
      var answer = 0;
      answer = passwd_chk(passwd,sqlpasswd);
      if(answer ===1){
          save_session(id);
          res.render('main');
      }


var save_session = function(req){
    req.session.id = req; 
}
```

i will post (login) and i save id in session but  this code is always err to cannot set property... how can i fix it?...
thanks for answer

Comment: This happens cause you're passing as `save_session(req)` the userId, and userId hasn't `session.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens cause you're passing `userId` as `save_session(req)` argument. Then you're doing `req.session.id = req;` in your case the same as `userId.session.id = userId;`. The error notices you that `userId` has not `session` property (Obsiously). All you need is pass `req` and `userId` as arguments. Change your code like this.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.body.userid;
  var passwd = req.body.password;
  var sess = req.session;
  var login_chk = pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
      connection.query('SELECT U_passwd FROM Member WHERE U_id = ?',[id],function(err,row,req){
         if(err)console.log(err);
      var sqlpasswd = row[0].U_passwd;
      var answer = 0;
      answer = passwd_chk(passwd,sqlpasswd);
      if(answer ===1){
          save_session(req,id);        <--- Change this
          res.render('main');
      }


var save_session = function(req,id){   <--- Change this
    req.session.id = id;               <--- Change this
}
```

I hope It helps.

Comment: thank you for your anwer! but there's same err to me ,
i console log req and id value req show [object object] and id value show my id value what can i do....

Comment: mmmmm print `console.log(req.session.id)` and tell me what value shows

Comment: i am sorry about your help i regret about session i use passport :'( thank for your help bless you